# How do I set up an adapter in zend framework 2?

Tags: database, zend-framework2, adapter

this is the content of the autoload/global.php file :

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'driver'         => 'Pdo',
        'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=web_builder;host=localhost',
        'driver_options' => array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
        ),
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'
                    => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
        ),
    ),
 );
```

this is the content of the autoload/local.php file:

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
        'username' => 'DB_User_Name',
        'password' => 'DB_Password',
 ,
);   )
```

this is part of the content of module/Module.php :

```
namespace Application;

use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;
.........
 public function getServiceConfig() {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'Application\Controller\UserController' => function($sm) {
                    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                    $table = new Model\StickyNotesTable($dbAdapter);
                    return $table;
                },
            ),
        );
    }
```

Here I really don't understand what this function do, I just copy pasted from  an example. If you could explain me what does getServiceConfig function do, I will really appreaciate it.

Finally the controller content:

```
    namespace Application\Controller;

    use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
    use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
    use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;
    use Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway;
    use Zend\Db\Sql\Select;


    class UserController extends AbstractActionController{

        public function __construct(Adapter $adapter) {
            $this->adapter = $adapter;
        }


        public function loginAction(){
            // here i just want to a simple select  and yes I know queries will be executed 
//in Model, but I want to here a simple query. 
//For example in Codeigniter I can't do in model, controller, or view as well.
            return new ViewModel();
        }
```

The result of all this code is obviously an error:
**Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Application\Controller\UserController::__construct() must be an instance of Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter, none given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\zf2\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager.php on line 170 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\zf2\module\Application\src\Application\Controller\UserController.php on line 21**

Can someone post an answer to make this database or query stuff work ? thx

Comment: why are you passing `Adapter $adapter`? as i can see you are already creating a factory for your table, another thing to see is that you are returning 1 table/model. Anyways `Adapter $adapter` is not required. If question is that you want to query only to that table then it is something else

Comment: @noobie-php can you give me an example without adapter ?

Comment: its simple you actually dont need to call the adapter in construtor, there are 2 main reasons, 1 : you are just calling `Adapter $adapter` since there is not Generic Adapter class you are getting error, 2nd you dont adapter coz you are setting the factory, now how to call a factory is somewhat like this `$UserControllerAdapter=$this->getServiceLocator()->get('Application\Controller\UserController');`

Comment: Another thing that you are doing terribly wrong here is that `Application\Controller\UserController => function($sm) {
                    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                    $table = new Model\StickyNotesTable($dbAdapter);
                    return $table;
                }`. You are passing a controller Name as factory, i suggest you take a look at zend frame work 2 skeleton app.